# ValueError: Couldn't find 'checkpoint' file or checkpoints in given directory with Google's image classification built-in algorithm

Tags: classification, tensorflow2.0, google-ai-platform

I've tried to fine-tune a resnet50 model following "[Getting started with the built-in image classification algorithm](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/algorithms/image-classification-start#gcloud)" tutorial. I have stored resnet 50 imagenet checkpoints (found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/vision/image_classification/resnet#pretrained-models)) in my google cloud storage (path is gs://my-bucket/classification/models/resnet-50). It contains the following:

```
model.ckpt-0090.index
model.ckpt-0090.data-00000-of-00002
model.ckpt-0090.data-00001-of-00002
```

When I submit the training job, I specify with argument `pretrained_checkpoint_path` the above path. When job starts, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Couldn't find 'checkpoint' file or checkpoints in given directory gs://my-bucket/classification/models/resnet-50
```

Should the name of the checkpoint files conform with some predefined format?

EDIT: actually, when uncompressed the checkpoints directory also contained the same 3 files as above but prefixed with `_.`. I got the error so I removed these prefixed files but with no more success.